# Fake local business added my website as his business website

Tags: seo, google, local-seo, google-maps, google-local-search

I've a website ranking serp #1 for lots of important keywords suddenly I found somenone registered his local business at google business but inserted my ranked page as his business website and google apporved it " I DO NOT How did google approved a page he doesn't own" so his business appear at all of keywords under my page results .
after some digging I found that the same business owner registered his business and add 6 different websites he doesn't own as his sites and that also helped his business to rank .

I tried to contact google support but they seem don't pay attention to us at Arabian World . so what I should do now to remove my site from his local business listing , and how to report the other listings to google to prevent him from steeling someone else effort and

Comment: "so his business appear at all of keywords under my page results" - I don't understand. Why would adding a website URL to a business listing change how that _business_ ranks in the SERPs?!

Answer (score 2):

*Google Local auto-approves the adding of website information*

Google generally auto-approves the adding of website data to the Google Local listing because its not in the interest of businesses to provide a incorrect website, as they will be sending traffic to them.

*Different business name but using my website*

If the business uses a different name but uses your website address then you simply need to [request they remove your information](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6174435?hl=en-GB) using the link provided.

*Google is slow... not just for middle east countries*

Google not responding to your emails is NOT a isolated ARAB matter... it happens to most if not all nations due to the fact that Google receives these requests in the hundreds of thousands and do not budget to make these changes quicker.

It is normal for users and businesses to have to wait several days to even many weeks for changes to take place on REQUEST, should it be Google Local or any other Google service, its normally slow but they do get around to it.

Comment: Push comes to shove, legal departments are often very responsive for requests that are non-threatening made by an attorney. It is a professional courtesy, one, and smart business second. Hiring an attorney to write a letter to Googles legal department should not cost very much since it will be a paralegal writing the letter. So for 1 hour or less of attorney time can likely solve this problem quickly. I hate to say get a lawyer, but sometimes, it is a good way to wake-up a company. I have gotten results this way for as little as $35.00. Cheers!!

Comment: Can I do that Saudi Arabia ?

Comment: The Problem is he's receiving calls at is business number some customers aren't satisfied with his services when they tried to call him he didn't answer their calls so the customers after that opened the website and called us (they been told that that fake business is one of hour branches ) thats why i'm looking for a fast solution

Comment: There is no fast solution. You need to contact Google and wait via suggested edits or the report button on Google Local. Google don't have operators for Google local on speed dial.